# How to lift state from a child widget up to another child widget

Tags: flutter

How would I lift a data from a child widget up to another child widget that's directly above it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Tree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TreeState createState() => _TreeState();
}

class _TreeState extends State<Tree> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          bigTree(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget bigTree() {
  var fruit = data; //Undefined name 'data'.


  return Container(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(fruit),
        smallTree(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget smallTree() {
  var data = 'apple'; //How to lift this data

  return Container(
    child: Text(data),
  );
}
```

I tried adding a constructor `_TreeState({this.data}); but it's coming up as null

Comment: Make the `data` variable a member of `_TreeState` class and assign the value in 'smallTree' but dont forget to call `smallTree`

Comment: i think thats the part i don't get. how do I call `smallTree`

Answer (score 2):

What you have aren't actually widgets. They're functions returning widgets. If you want the bigTree to "hold state" in flutter's traditional meaning, you'd need to make it into a class which extends `StatefulWidget` and implements create state as your `Tree` widget does. Currently, as functions, every time you'd hot reload, the variables in your widget returning functions would be reset and thus no "state" is present.

Here is how I'd change things

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Tree extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          BigTree(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BigTree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BigTreeState createState() => _BigTreeState();
}

class _BigTreeState extends State<BigTree> {
  final fruit = 'apple';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(fruit),
          SmallTree(fruit),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SmallTree extends StatelessWidget {
  SmallTree(this.data);

  final String data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(data),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Nolence answer is good. I want to give more general. I am begginer, however this is how I understand:

### With simple setState.

You let parent widget to manage the state. You pass all usefull 'tools' to the stateless child widget where action occurs.

```dart
class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // used tools
    final var inputData;
    final Function changeData;
    ChildWidget(this.inputData, this.changeData);

    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  Container(
            ...
                // action
                onTap: () {
                  changeData(inputData);
                },

                // data usage
                Text('My changed ${inputData.toString()}'),
```

Implement logic (define tools) in the parent widget:

```dart
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  // define tools and pass to child
  var inputData = 0;

  void changeData(var outputData) {
    // Implement logic
    print(outputData);
    setState(() {
      inputData += outputData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        ...
        ChildWidget(inputData, changeData),
```

When the changeData function will be used it will call statefull widget to change the state and rebuild the tree (render).

[image]